# set the texture for by glUniform1i

Tags: opengl

I have a question about how to set the texture by `glUniform1i`. I have seen code like below.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);
glUniform1i(_textureUniform, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glUniform1i(_textureUniform, 1);
```

Does it mean, if I use the number `i` in the `glUniform1i`, then I have to use `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE **i** )`?

Comment: Similar to https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/5063/send-texture-to-shader

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The uniform value for a sampler refers to the texture unit, not the texture id.