# OpenGL and QtQuick Texture Problems (revisited)

Tags: c++, opengl-es, textures, qt-quick

According to this post [OpenGL and QtQuick Texture Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953671/opengl-and-qtquick-texture-problems), ensuring that you unbind the texture id associated with an active texture solved my initial problem. Which was, calls to glActiveTexture, etc. were destroying `Text` objects I have defined in my QML. Thus the code below works.

```
void draw()
{
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo); GL_CALL 
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ebo); GL_CALL

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); GL_CALL     
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_tex[0]); GL_CALL
  glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(m_handle.shaderProgramId(), "uSampler1"), 0);
  GL_CALL

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); GL_CALL     
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_tex[1]); GL_CALL
  glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(m_handle.shaderProgramId(), "uSampler2"), 1);
  GL_CALL

  ...

  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_indices.get_indices_count(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
    0); GL_CALL

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); GL_CALL     
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); GL_CALL   
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); GL_CALL     
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); GL_CALL
}
```

However, if I change the code to look like:

```
void draw()
{
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo); GL_CALL 
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ebo); GL_CALL

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE20); GL_CALL     
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_tex[0]); GL_CALL
  glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(m_handle.shaderProgramId(), "uSampler1"), 20);
  GL_CALL

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE21); GL_CALL     
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_tex[1]); GL_CALL
  glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(m_handle.shaderProgramId(), "uSampler2"), 21);
  GL_CALL

  ...

  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_indices.get_indices_count(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
    0); GL_CALL

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE21); GL_CALL     
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); GL_CALL   
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE20); GL_CALL     
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); GL_CALL
}
```

The issue of improperlly rendered QML `Text` objects returns. All I did was change which texture was active and according to [set the texture for by glUniform1i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661878/set-the-texture-for-by-gluniform1i) I am making sure to update the call to glUniform1i. What else could be causing QML labels to be rendered incorrectly? Would images of the problem be helpful?